# условие if работает некорректно

Tags: php, вконтакте, if

Это бот VK. Код должен работать так: Я отправляю ему "1", он делает &flag = true и отправляет мне сообщение "Введите новую строку". После, я ввожу сообщение, бот записывает его в базу данных, отправляет мне сообщение "Строка записана" и делает $flag = false, чтобы мои сообщения больше не записывались.
 Но проблема в том, что условие 2 не работает, как надо. Хоть я и поставил, чтобы body не было равно "1", условие все равно выполняется, и единица заносится в базу. (см. картинку ниже).
Что мне сделать, чтобы этот код работал, как я описал выше?

```
if ($data->object->body == 1) //условие 1
            {
                $flag = true;
                $request_params = array( 
                    'message' => "Введите новую строку", 
                    'user_id' => $user_id, 
                    'access_token'=> getenv('VK_TOKEN'),
                    'v' => '5.69'      ); 

            }

if ($flag && $data->object->body != 1) // условие 2
            {
                $qer = $data->object->body;
                $request_params = array( 
                    'message' => "Строка записана: '$qer'", 
                    'user_id' => $user_id, 
                    'access_token'=> getenv('VK_TOKEN'),
                    'v' => '5.69'      );   
                $query = "INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (NULL, '$qer');";
                $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
                $flag = false;

            }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, это происходит из-за того, что в строке `if ($data->object->body == 1)` вы проверяете данные на равенство, а в строке `if ($flag && $data->object->body !== 1)` на идентичность. Данные в `$data->object->body` приходят в строковом формате, а вы проверяете `$data->object->body !== (integer)1`.

Попробуйте сделать во втором варианте проверку на равенство (`!=`).

Comment: Окей, как тогда мне проверить строку, используя оператор "не"?
С `==` пробовал. Записывается только "1", и никакие другие комбинации.

Comment: `!=` - самый адекватный вариант в данном случае. Изменил ответ.

Comment: сделал, после того, как мне выводится "Введите новую строку" и я ее ввожу, ничего не происходит. В теме изменил картинку

Comment: Где идет инициализация $flag?

Comment: Под 'условием 1'. Стоит это делать раньше?

Comment: Конечно. Php не видит переменную `$flag` и выбрасывает ошибку `$flag is not defined`. Если зайдете по ссылке в браузере, то увидите её.

Comment: Если при инициализации сделать `$flag = true`, то все работает, то есть при написании строки она записывается в базу, но если сделать `$flag = false`, то под "условием 1" похоже не выполняется `$flag = true;`, ибо происходит то же самое, что и на скриншоте вверху.